# Symfony2 - Form submit does not work depending on a route of page

Tags: forms, symfony, routes, submit, form-submit

So I have this route:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    // ...
```

In this page is a correct form that was working some time ago.

```
{{ form_start(company_sign_up_form, {'action': path('homepage', { 'sign_up': 'company' }) }) }}
```

Here `sign_up` is a parameter that I am passing through the url.

Example: `http://localhost/?sign_up=company`

When I am submitting form I am redirected to the page without this `sign_up` parameter and both `$form->isSubmitted()` and `$form->isValid()` are giving me `false`.

But when I change the route from `@Route("/", name="homepage")` to `@Route("/something", name="homepage")` the submit is working just fine.

The only similar route that could conflict is the dynamic one:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{page}", name="public", requirements={"page": "about|programs|contacts"})
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $page
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function publicAction(Request $request, $page)
{
```

I tried changing this route to different, but it does not fix my issue.

Does anyone know the problem, why my form is not submitting properly with current route?

**UPDATE**

So I overcame the issue by modifying the route my form is in and refers to.

```
/**
 * @Route("/{page}", name="homepage", defaults={"page": ""}, requirements={"page": "|home"})
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
```

So in this case I can access my homepage by `http://localhost/` and `http://localhost/home` so if I set form action to `/home`, my form is submitted successfully.

Anyway, this is not the solution or answer, I leave it as it is and wait for better solution.

Comment: your form validation is failing.  This probably works in the publicAction with '/something' because that action is not checking for a valid (?) form like `indexAction`.  Check the constraints on the entity you persist with that form.  Also if you post your formtype, and your entity class, it could be better debugged here.  I don't think this is due to your routing.

Comment: But why I do not get "sign_up" parameter that I am passing with form action attr? Usually when constraint fails I still am redirected with parameter I pass with form action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end problem was caused by login form. I had to modify `check_path` of each area that login logic would not be executed in same page as other forms.

```
main:
    pattern:    ^
    anonymous:  ~
    provider:   main
    context:    primary_auth
    form_login:
        login_path:             /
        check_path:             /login_check
        default_target_path:    /authorization
    logout:
        path: /logout
        target: homepage
    remember_me:
        secret: '%secret%'
        lifetime: 31536000
```